# Cannot add the Tag "securityCryptographyConfiguration " in web.config

Tags: c#, cryptography, enterprise-library

I need to add the Tag `securityCryptographyConfiguration` in the web.config in order to use the MS Application blocks 4.1 for Cryptography. This tag is available in `app.config(Windows)`.

Please help me to place this tag in web.config.

Comment: which is your ***web.config*** ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the section handler? If not, you'll need to add this to your `<configSections>` element:

```
<section name="securityCryptographyConfiguration"
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.Configuration.CryptographySettings,
           Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography,
           Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Once you have that in place, you should be able to add the securityCryptographyConfiguration tag to your web.config, remembering that it sits on it's own, it doesn't nest inside another section e.g.:

```
</configSections>

<!-- The crypt config section sits at the same level as configSections
<securityCryptographyConfiguration />

<system.web>
```